# Hovering effect not working on mobile because of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Something strange is happening. My two files named `register.html` and `login.html` have the following structure:

register.html

```
<body id="register-section">
</body>
```

login.html

```
<body id="login-section">
    <p id="forgot">Passwort vergessen?</p>
</body>
```

If you hover over `Passwort vergessen?`, the text will be unterlined using CSS:

```
#forgot:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Now if I add the following line in JavaScript, which only runs when `register.html` is open, I can't make `Passwort vergessen?` produce the hover effect on mobile devices. It basically disables it, but it works on my computer! **Only on mobile devices this is not the case.**

```
if (document.getElementById('register-section')) {
    // Do something ONLY related to #register-section
}
```

If I remove the JavaScript line, the hovering effect works again on mobile devices. You can check it here: http://2gear.de

The JavaScript line also never gets executed because I can do

```
else {
    alert('test');
}
```

and the alert gets executed. Pretty strange.

Comment: How are these two HTML pages related?

Comment: Are you loading the same JS into both pages, and using that `if` statement to tell which page it is?

Comment: @Barmar yes I am loading the same JS into both pages and using the if statement to tell which page it is

Comment: @Barmar Furthermore with my index.html I only load `login.html` with the following: `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/login.html'>`

Comment: @Barmar how can I load both `login.html` and `register.html` into my `index.html`?

Comment: I loaded your page into Chrome on my iPhone and hovering over `Passwort vergessen` gets the underline effect.

Comment: You can't load them both into index.html unless you use iframes.

Comment: @Barmar can you test Safari aswell please? Because on my iPhone it won't work ...

Comment: I confirm, it doesn't work in Safari. It pops up a menu. I think the problem is that the same gesture (press-hold) is used for both right-click and hover, and it's preferring the right-click action.